# Dependent drop-down menu not working as expected in Safari - triggering false-positive validation error

Tags: html, safari, frontend

I have a form with a dependent field which appears to be working fine on all browsers except Safari. When using Safari, the user gets a validation error saying "This field is required" on the Place Name field even if it is filled in. The validation error is a false-positive and it means the user cannot submit the form.

I think it is almost certainly something to do with the fact that the Place Name field consists of 2 dependent fields - on the first dropdown, you have to select either "Central" or "County regional centre", and on the second dropdown (which only displays if you selected "County regional centre" on the first drop-down), you have to select the relevant county centre. The validation error doesn't appear if you select "County regional centre" in the first dropdown and then select a county centre in the second dropdown, so that scenario is fine. The false-positive validation error only appears if you select "Central" in the first dropdown. In that scenario, the second dropdown doesn't appear (as it is only relevant for regional users). So I suspect Safari is expecting the user to select a value in that second drop-down menu, even though it is hidden from the user and not required to be filled-in in that scenario.

No errors are showing in the Safari developer console when I try to either open the form or submit it.

This is the code for the relevant part of the form (I have omitted many of the options in the second dropdown menu as it's very long):

```
<fieldset class="content">
<legend>Details</legend>
<ul class="form-controls">
    <span data-hide="true" resource="this:place-1" typeof="place:Place"></span>                     
    <span data-hide="true" resource="this:place-case-1" typeof="place:PlaceCase"></span>                        
    <li class="">
        <label for="this-place-1_place-placeName-1">Place Name:                         </label>
        <select id="this-place-1_place-placeName-1" name="this:place-1[place:placeName]" required="required" aria-required="true" class="conditional-field-control" data-conditional-field-target="#this-place-2_place-countyPlaceName-1" data-conditional-field-show-when="County regional centre">
            <option disabled="disabled"> Please Select</option>
            <option value="Central">Central</option>
            <option value="County regional centre">County regional centre</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <label for="this-place-2_place-countyPlaceName-1">                      </label>
        <select id="this-place-2_place-countyPlaceName-1" name="this:place-1[place:countyPlaceName]" required="required" aria-required="true" class="data-setter" data-setter-target="#this-notifiableThing_corp-insolvency-nameOfPlaceOfRegional-1">
            <option disabled="disabled"> Please choose from the following regional centres: (if applicable)</option>
            <option value="Aberystwyth">Aberystwyth</option>
            <option value="Aldershot and Farnham">Aldershot and Farnham</option>
            <option value="Aylesbury">Aylesbury</option>
            <option value="Barrow-in-Furness">Barrow-in-Furness</option>
            <option value="York">York</option>
        </select>
    <li class="partial-submit"><input class="btn-hidden-js btn-partial-submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" name="select-place" type="submit" value="Select Place" /></li>
    </li>                                       
</ul>
```